# Strange (interpolated maybe) values from openlayers canvas

Tags: webgl, openlayers, openlayers-6

I create an openlayers map application for creating histogram from COG layer. I using WebGLTile layer and DataTile source. In a map I have only 2 colors but `gl.readPixels` returns 12 color values.

[map screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuP1I.png)

part of code:

```
map.on("click", (evt) => {
  var buffer = {};

  const gl = webgl.getRenderer().helper.getGL();
  const pixelData = new Uint8Array(gl.drawingBufferWidth * gl.drawingBufferHeight * 4);

  gl.readPixels(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData);

  let r, g, b, c = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < pixelData.length; i+=4) {
    r = pixelData[i];
    g = pixelData[i+1];
    b = pixelData[i+2];

    let item;
    item = [r, g, b].reduce((acc, cur) => {
      if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(cur)) {
        acc[cur] = {};
      }

      return acc[cur];
    }, buffer);

    item.count = (item.count || 0) + 1;
  }
});
```

In final buffer I need only

```
{
"165": {
    "1": {
        "38": {
            "count": 1181613
        }
    },
},
"255": {
    "255": {
        "191": {
            "count": 351
        }
    }
}
```

}

but I get 12 colors between these two intervals.

```
{
"165": {
    "1": {
        "38": {
            "count": 1181613
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "39": {
            "count": 130473
        }
    }
},
"168": {
    "10": {
        "43": {
            "count": 130413
        }
    }
},
"169": {
    "11": {
        "44": {
            "count": 15151
        }
    }
},
"174": {
    "27": {
        "54": {
            "count": 130481
        }
    },
    "28": {
        "54": {
            "count": 14792
        }
    }
},
"177": {
    "36": {
        "59": {
            "count": 14460
        }
    }
},
"178": {
    "37": {
        "59": {
            "count": 1631
        }
    }
},
"242": {
    "219": {
        "170": {
            "count": 130366
        }
    }
},
"243": {
    "220": {
        "170": {
            "count": 14487
        }
    }
},
"246": {
    "228": {
        "175": {
            "count": 14884
        }
    },
    "229": {
        "175": {
            "count": 1574
        }
    }
},
"251": {
    "245": {
        "185": {
            "count": 15250
        }
    }
},
"252": {
    "246": {
        "186": {
            "count": 1586
        }
    }
},
"255": {
    "254": {
        "190": {
            "count": 1528
        }
    },
    "255": {
        "191": {
            "count": 351
        }
    }
}
```

}

I have no idea why is this happenning and I spent days searching for solution.
I found some example, not with openlayers, and this approach was fine. returns only two values from double-color square.
It's some kind of interpolation on the openlayers side?

Thnaks for any help!

Comment: WebGL anti-aliasing is enabled by default.  Try setting `preserveDrawingBuffer: true, antialias: false` in the context options

Comment: I tried this options, but without success